# Elasticsearch cluster backup

Tags: elasticsearch

I followed the blog http://chrissimpson.co.uk/elasticsearch-snapshot-restore-api.html
to take backup of my elasticsearch cluster having 6 nodes(3 master,3data). When I execute

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/es_backup/_all'
```

I got response having the snapshot details with all indices

```
{"snapshots":[{"snapshot":"snapshot_1","indices".....
```

the stattus of indices backup is failed and it says the reason is

```
indices don't have primary shards elasticsearch
```

What would be the problem. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I did a mistake we need to give our cluster name in the url. I given some different name so it got failed.